# Migrating password from firebase to postgres problem

Tags: php, firebase, scrypt, migrating

I need your help, SOF.
I want to migrate users from Firebase to a PostgreSQL database, but my issue is with the hashed passwords stored by Firebase.

How can I verify if a plain-text password matches a hash provided by Firebase? I can't figure it out :/

Thank you in advance.

I try some PHP and github function

Comment: Just create a new account and compare the hashes.

Comment: It depends how the passwords were originally hashed, which you haven't told us

Comment: Firebase specifies what hash function was determined for each password, you'll have to apply that same hash and compare the values (as Markus said).

Comment: Run both auth methods in parallel for a time, when a user logs in has no hash in pgsql, auth against firebase, and on success add the new hash to pgsql. After a "suitable" amount of time turn off firebase and require users who aren't in pgsql to reset their passwords.